# I am unable to edit the value where already presented values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the scaffold I create one project I did't update the value  where it be there in pgadmin but I able too create and destroy   and the code for the update is

```
@department = Department.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @department.update_attributes(params[:departments])
    flash[:notice] = 'Department was successfully updated.'
    format.html { redirect_to(@department) }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @department.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with your config/routes.rb

You should have something like `resources :departments` there. can you post your routes.rb and full controller code here (if didn't find error by yourself).

**UPDATE**

Looking closer on error I would suppose that you are using `resource` in your routes instead of `resources`.